# Drift in rotation about z-axis

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In an application, while trying to rotate an object using touch, I noticed drift in position   of object after sometime (without any translation applied !!). The rotation is only about z-axis and works perfectly, but drift happens only after few rotations.

`ds` <kbd>will be used</kbd> for translation (using up-down button).

`_uNozzleCentreMatrix` and `_ModelMatrixNozzle` <kbd>will use</kbd> `ds` if I correct this.

```
private static final float[] _uNozzleCentre     = new float[]{0.0f, 0.333605f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
protected static float[] _uNozzleCentreMatrix   = new float[4];

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.setLookAtM(GLES20Renderer._ViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 7f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.frustumM(GLES20Renderer._ProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 8);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
}
private static void updateModel(int upDown, float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle) {
    //ds                = GLES20Renderer._upDown - GLES20Renderer._lastUpDown;
    ds = 0; // ds changes with button up-down, but now it is made 0, so button up-down will not affect it
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre, 0);
    if(Math.abs(ds) > 0) {
    } else {
        if(GLES20Renderer._zAngle >= 360) {
            GLES20Renderer._zAngle = GLES20Renderer._zAngle - 360;
        }
        if(GLES20Renderer._zAngle <= -360) {
            GLES20Renderer._zAngle = GLES20Renderer._zAngle + 360;
        }
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._lastZAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
    }
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._ViewMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._ProjectionMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0);

    GLES20Renderer._lastZAngle = zAngle;
}
```

**Apk for download:**

http://www.pixdip.com/opengles/rotation/rotation.apk

(Try swiping a longer horizontal area from extreme left to right to observe drift early. Please be patient! Drift can take 20 seconds to occur)

For those whom it did not happen, here is the automated apk:
http://www.pixdip.com/opengles/rotation/automatic.apk

and the edited part of code:

```
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        //Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._lastZAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
```

Comment: What thread and method is calling "updateModel"? If this is wired to anything but "draw" method it could present a problem you described.

Comment: ondrawframe is calling updatemodel. All of this is in renderer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes floating point errors get accumulated because of matrix stack.

This can be removed by using separate matrices for some critical transformations:

```
private static float[] _TMatrix = new float[16];
private static float[] _ModelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentity(Renderer._ModelMatrix);
Matrix.setIdentity(Renderer._TMatrix);
Matrix.translate(Renderer._ModelMatrix, xmov,ymov,0);
Matrix.translate(Renderer._TMatrix, -xmov,-ymov,0);
Matrix.multiply(Renderer._ModelMatrix, Renderer._TMatrix, Renderer._ModelMatrix);
// will result in an identity model matrix, without any floating point errors
```