# safeguard against floating point errors in java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, floating-point

As the number of frames rendered in a game increase beyond a certain 
 limit, instead of obtaining an identity matrix for the following type of matrix transformation:

```
Matrix.setIdentity(ModelMatrix);
Matrix.translate(ModelMatrix, xmov,ymov,0);
Matrix.translate(ModelMatrix, -xmov,-ymov,0);
```

there are small values that get added to the columns (because of floating point errors in java), and progressively become larger in the matrix (which is no longer identity) and causes strange translations. Below is the code:

```
    ...// _ModelMatrixNozzle is set as identity matrix like all other 4x4 matrices in my app in onSurfaceChanged method
    ...// this code is part of update() method, called by onDrawFrame() in renderer thread
    GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0] = GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[0] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[0] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[4] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[1] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[8] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[2] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[12] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[3];
    GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1] = GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[1] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[0] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[5] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[1] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[9] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[2] + GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle[13] * GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre[3];
    GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[2] = 0;
    GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[3] = 1;
    if(Math.abs(ds) > 0) {
        /*transformations will be added here if the errors are solved*/
    } else {
        if(GLES20Renderer._zAngle >= 360) {
            GLES20Renderer._zAngle = GLES20Renderer._zAngle - 360;
        }
        if(GLES20Renderer._zAngle <= -360) {
            GLES20Renderer._zAngle = GLES20Renderer._zAngle + 360;
        }
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        //Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._lastZAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        Matrix.translateM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0], -GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1], 0);
    }
```

Download apk:**http://www.pixdip.com/opengles/rotation/floating.apk**

Although this is <kbd>not required</kbd>, but the complete code is here:**[Drift in rotation about z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196614/drift-in-rotation-about-z-axis)**

Comment: Your text makes statements but does not ask a question. From the title, we might figure you want to avoid drift over repeated operations. But you give no context that would help in answering your questions. Must the translation and its inverse be an identity operation, exactly? Or is it sufficient to limit drift over many operations? Can the translation amounts be quantized? Can the ModelMatrix be quantized? Can you increase the floating-point precision used? What are the magnitudes of the translation amounts relative to the position amounts?

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix.setIdentity(ModelMatrix);
Matrix.translate(ModelMatrix, xmov,ymov,0);
Matrix.translate(ModelMatrix, -xmov,-ymov,0);
```

Will always produce floating point errors because of matrix stack.

The way I finally removed this was by using seperate matrices for such critical transformations:

```
private static float[] _TMatrix = new float[16];
private static float[] _ModelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentity(Renderer._ModelMatrix);
Matrix.setIdentity(Renderer._TMatrix);
Matrix.translate(Renderer._ModelMatrix, xmov,ymov,0);
Matrix.translate(Renderer._TMatrix, -xmov,-ymov,0);
Matrix.multiply(Renderer._ModelMatrix, Renderer._TMatrix, Renderer._ModelMatrix);
// will result in an identity model matrix, without any floating point errors
```